# Can a Gmail gadget use users.get_current_user()?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-gadget

I'm trying to get the current user for a Gmail gadget, but it seems `users.get_current_user()` returns `None`, even though I'm obviously logged in.

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the Users API directly within a Gmail gadget, but you can use [a combination of OpenID and the gadgets APIs](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/marketplace/best_practices#gadget_sso) to authenticate your users. The document was writing in the context of a Gmail contextual gadget (which is installed via the Google Apps Marketplace), but the principles will still apply for non-contextual gadgets.

The biggest difference between what is outlined in the document and what happens in a non-contextual gadget is that Google Apps Marketplace applications (and their companion gadgets) are automatically whitelisted for OpenID. Without a Marketplace install, users will see an OpenID approval screen the first time they load your gadget.

Answer (score 1):

get_current_user returns the user who is log on into YOUR domain, in Gmail widget the user is log in into gmail.

Comment: hmm, so basically get_current_user doesn't work in a contextual Gmail gadget?